# How to obscure only 1 String or the whole activity

Tags: android, android-studio, obscured-view

I want to obscures only 1 String .
He is here ,

```
package x.y.z

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
String url = "https://example.com/app_update/userdata.json";
.
.
.
`
}
```

How to obscures it please help

Comment: can you explain more about your requirement? do you want this string not readable in the compiled apk? also what is it that you have tried till now?

Comment: can you explain more about your requirement? do you want this string not readable in the compiled apk? also what is it that you have tried till now?

Comment: Mohit Bhaee I want to obscure the url, If someone decompiled my app, So it should not show my url. I want something like this

Answer (score 0):

I would just do it manually. You could generate it out of parts or use some sort of encryption.

Here is also an example how to do it: https://gist.github.com/slevental/0c902da60a1f6f931420